# Publish Data Source Greyed Out in Tableau desktop

Tags: sql-server, datasource, tableau-api

I have installed tableau desktop and when I am going to publish my data source which retrieves from SQL on premises database to tableau online server, the publish option is greyed out(disabled). I have logged in to the server and I have also permissions to publish data sources. Still I can not find a solution. 
Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that versions of Tableau Server and Tableau Desktop are compatible.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/desktopdeploy/en-us/desktop_deploy_compatibility.htm

If your current Tableau Desktop version is not compatible with current Tableau Server version, then download correct/matching version here:

https://www.tableau.com/support/releases

Comment: Is this publishing to Tableau online via bridge? Is your bridge client running on the machine you are publishing from?

Comment: Do I need to install any driver?

Comment: No driver should be necessary to connect/publish to Tableau Online.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to publish to Tableau Online, or an on-premise Tableau Server instance? How exactly are you logging on to the server machine, and what hostname are you using?